# Zend PDF - want to open instead of saving

Tags: zend-framework

am generating pdf using Zend_pdf

its saving after creating

I want to open it instead of saving.

When i access the url directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to open a PDF directly, so I did this instead:

```
<?php
// Save PDF into file
$oPdf->save("./pdfcache/filename.pdf");

// Set headers
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');

// Get File Contents and echo to output
echo file_get_contents("./pdfcache/filename.pdf");

// Prevent anything else from being outputted
die();
```

It's not perfect, but it does the job for me.

Answer (score 12):

Use render() method

```
// Set PDF headers
header ('Content-Type:', 'application/pdf');
header ('Content-Disposition:', 'inline;');

// Output pdf
echo $pdf->render();
```